# How do I / Is it posssible to keep different picture in each side of box() in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, p5.js

As beginner in P5.js I am trying to make a interactive dice, where the only trouble now is keeping different faces in each side in the cube.

Here is my code:

```
let sizeOfCube = 400, img;

function preload() {
    img = loadImage("olo/fgfg.jpg");
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
    background(250);
    translate(0, 0, sizeOfCube);
    if (sizeOfCube > 100) {
        sizeOfCube -= 10;
    }
    rotateX(frameCount * 0.1);
    rotateY(frameCount * (0.1));
    rotateZ(frameCount * 0.1);
    texture(img);
    box(70, 70, 70);
}
```

This code adds the image but is applied to all the sides. Is there a way to add 6 images to all 6 sides?

For a demo(texture and others) please visit [here](https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/425446) `Might take some time to load. Please wait!`

> Any suggestion or alternative approach? Please do tell.

Comment: can you please share the texture so it's easier to everyone else to test/reproduce the behaviour you're getting ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/425446 . I have edited my post and added a link to a demo. https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/425446 here is it too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a working solution here. I tried the suggestion to use quad above and draw each face one by one using texture and rotation. I have also abstracted the drawFaceBox function out so that you can reuse it easily by passing in your own dimensions.

```
function preload() {
  BOX_WIDTH = 1083;
  BOX_HEIGHT = 1457;
  BOX_DEPTH = 345;
  FRONT_IMG = loadImage('images/front.png');
  LEFT_IMG = loadImage('images/left.png');
  TOP_IMG = loadImage('images/top.png');
  RIGHT_IMG = loadImage('images/right.png');
  BOTTOM_IMG = loadImage('images/bottom.png');
  BACK_IMG = loadImage('images/back.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  // Make sure the box always fit the screen.
  SCALE_FACTOR = windowHeight / 2 /
      Math.max(Math.max(BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT), BOX_DEPTH);
}

function drawFaceBox(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth,
    front, top, right, bottom, left, back) {
  angleMode(DEGREES); 
  let w = boxWidth * SCALE_FACTOR;
  let h = boxHeight * SCALE_FACTOR;
  let d = boxDepth * SCALE_FACTOR;

  // Center the box.
  translate(-w / 2, -h / 2);

  texture(front);
  quad(0, 0, w, 0, w, h, 0, h);

  push();
  texture(left);
  translate(0, 0, -d);
  rotateY(-90);
  quad(0, 0, d, 0, d, h, 0, h);

  pop();
  push();
  texture(top);
  translate(0, 0, -d);
  rotateX(90);
  quad(0, 0, w, 0, w, d, 0, d);

  pop();
  push();
  texture(right);
  translate(w, 0, 0);
  rotateY(90);
  quad(0, 0, d, 0, d, h, 0, h);

  pop();
  push();
  texture(bottom);
  translate(0, h, 0);
  rotateX(-90);
  quad(0, 0, w, 0, w, d, 0, d);

  pop();
  push();
  texture(back);
  rotateY(180);
  translate(-w, 0, d);
  quad(0, 0, w, 0, w, h, 0, h);
}

function draw() {
  background(50);

  // Simple rotation control by mouse.
  rotateX(mouseY);
  rotateY(-mouseX);

  drawFaceBox(BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT, BOX_DEPTH,
      FRONT_IMG, TOP_IMG, RIGHT_IMG, BOTTOM_IMG, LEFT_IMG, BACK_IMG);
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. That is a lot of code for an answer, could you add a few comments on how you achieved the answer and how it solves the OP's problem so that we could all benefit more from your expertise, thanks!

Comment: You need to add a final pop() in the drawFaceBox() to match the push() call

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would want to draw the cube yourself using the `quad()` function along with whatever texture you want for each side.

More info is available in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/quad).

Comment: I have tried that : The syntax is as `quad(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4)` . In 3d there are 3 axes so what do i do for z-axis?

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya In regular Processing, you would just add the Z coordinates after the Y coordinates. If that doesn't work, try the `plane()` function from the P5.js reference?

Comment: using Z co-ordinates didn't work :(. `plane()` gives a kind of 2D shape in 3D space so that won't help me.